# Is asking a list of movies for a specific category on-topic or off-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is asking a list of movies for a specific category on-topic or off-topic here?

**Example question :** A list of movies about motivation (specially tech startups, for businessmen etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. off-topic here.

If you take a look at the close reasons, you will find one saying,

> Recommendation questions asking for movies/TV-shows or resources to locate or watch movie/TV content are off topic. Feel free to ask for people's opinion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) or take a look at [this related question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9301/27264) for general guidance on finding what you're looking for.

Generally, recommendation questions are off-topic on SE except a few one such as Hardware and Software recommendations because they tend to get opinion-based and a large number of answers thus making them primarily opinion-based and too broad.